# Javascript large array of objects cannot be sorted for aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting, aggregate

Trying to process a snapshot from a database, we have over **2.5 million** objects in the array, each object has an index property that is based on increments starting at an arbitrary number, in this case `45000`.

Using a sort method `myArray.sort((a,b)=> a.index - b.index)` leaves the array fragmented.

example:

- dataset index starts at 45000
- `myArray[0]` correctly logs 45000
- `myArray[myArray.length-1]` correctly logs 2545000
- `myArray[1]` is incorrectly 45007

I thought the data was missing from the snapshot, but confirmed through:
`myArray.findIndex(e => e.index == 45001)`
reports index `12532` and the value is present in the serialized json file that is 1.4GB in size.

I have serialized with a read/write stream with each line containing the JSON.stringified object

Should I move to a Collection Map instead of an array? would `.get()` be efficient?
I am currently using a For loop and iterating by index
then finding the actual index to ensure they are incremental but its by far the slowest method.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < maxIndex- minIndex; i++) {
    let obj = myArray.find(e => e.index == i + minIndex)
    if(!obj){ 
       console.log("missing index", i + minIndex);
       continue;
    }
    // process object
}
```

Comment: no database is involved @Nick - This is more likely heap error when manipulating the array itself.

Comment: What I meant was that when you produce the snapshot you should produce a sorted snapshot...

Comment: that is out of the scope of this question, a band-aid solution for a process that would take hours to generate a snapshot with queries is horribly inefficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There appears to be some technical limitations with the `.sort()` functions on larger arrays. if you know the data set is large in volume, its easier to cast to a new array

```js
    let newArray = new Array(maxIndex - minIndex + 1).fill(null);
    myArray.forEach(e => newArray [e.index - maxIndex ] = e);
    for (let i = 0; i < newArray .length; i++) {}
```